# Sed command not working:Observed sed: unmatched '#'

Tags: linux, sed

Inside Following `dert.ini` file i have a string like this

```
LOG.RDK.SI = FATAL ERROR WARNING
```

using `sed` command iam trying to replace `LOG.RDK.SI = FATAL ERROR WARNING` with

```
LOG.RDK.SI = FATAL ERROR WARNING INFO
```

This is the sed command i used..

```
root@FRT1v3:~# sed -i s#LOG.RDK.SI = FATAL ERROR WARNING#LOG.RDK.SI = FATAL ERROR WARNING INFO#g /opt/dert.ini
```

While executing this command I observed

```
sed: unmatched '#'
```

whats wrong with the sed command iam using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. sed script should be quoted,
2. regex-active characters should be escaped with backslashes,
3. `&` on the replacement side expands to matched substring.

```
sed -i 's#LOG\.RDK\.SI = FATAL ERROR WARNING#& INFO#g' /opt/dert.ini
```